# Fixing train and test set in `caret`

Tags: r, machine-learning, r-caret

What I want to do is run `caret` with full control of the train and test set. To that end, I create the training indices like so:

```
> trainIndex <- createDataPartition(iris$Species, p=0.75, list=FALSE);
```

Now what I want to do is, for every `k` from `1` to `5`, train the `knn` model on the training data and test it on the rest. As I understand, the `index` and `indexOut` parameters control that.

I tried running the code below:

```
library(caret)
data(iris)
trainIndex <- createDataPartition(iris$Species, p=0.75, list=FALSE);
train(Species~., data=iris, method='knn', 
      tuneGrid=data.frame(k=1:5), 
      trControl=trainControl(method='boot', index=list(Resample1=trainIndex[,]),
      indexOut=list(Resample1=setdiff(1:150, trainIndex[,])), savePredictions = TRUE))
```

But it's returning an error:

```
Error in train.default(x, y, weights = w, ...) : Stopping
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In eval(expr, envir, enclos) :
  model fit failed for Resample1: k=1 Error in x[modelIndex, , drop = FALSE] : subscript out of bounds
```

Can anyone explain to me what I am doing wrong? I cannot wrap my head around my mistake.

Comment: Your example code runs fine. Make sure you start with a clean r session. It looks like your trainIndex contained the values from the previous assignment and not with the records from the iris data set.

Comment: @phiver You're right.